# Computing a weight relative to 2 bounds

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to crack a trivial-for-some-of-us math problem with no success. End product should be a nice and clean Excel formula.

We consider here a monthly consumption of cups of coffee in an office. Each stop in the table is distant from the preceding by 200 cups. (i.e. headings read 200, 400, 600, etc. cups a month). For each of these stops, I calculated packaging costs related to the level of consumption we consider.

Issue is when we consider an intermediate consumption value, say 720 cups / month. This falls between 2 columns in the table. 720 is closer to 800 than it is to 600. The formula I am looking for would therefore be something like:

> w * (packaging cost related to 600 cups /month) + w’ * (packaging costs related to 800 cups / month)
>
> Where : w (w=200-120/200 in our example) and w’ = 1-w

Can’t do this elegantly without a series of ‘if’s’… What would you do?

Comment: You might be interested in [`MROUND`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/mround-function-c299c3b0-15a5-426d-aa4b-d2d5b3baf427) > e.g.: Something along the lines of `=MROUND(A1,200)`

Comment: @JvdV saw this formula for the first time thanks for bring it up :) Hopefully I can use it in future cases.

Comment: I think I misread your question and came up an incorrect answer. Could you please confirm if the calculation for `w` is `=200-(120/200)` which is `199.4` or `=(200-120)/200` which is `0.4`? It is very important to clarify this formula as it will alter the final answer. Let me know so I can update my solution for you. Also can you please share your current formula which has a lot of **IF**s so I can compare if my solution is more efficient or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to round `A1` **down** to the closest product of 200, you can use this:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1 / 200, 0) * 200
```

Similarly, you can use `ROUNDUP`.
Then, in order to calculate your `w`, you can use the following formula:

```
= 200 - (A1 - ROUNDDOWN(A1 / 200, 0) * 200) / 200
```

And then you're a `VLOOKUP` away from finding the relevant prices by their location in your pricing table.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

[image]

Formula in cell D4

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A2:B7,2,1)+((VLOOKUP(D2+200,A2:B7,2,1)-VLOOKUP(D2,A2:B7,2,1))/200)*(D2-VLOOKUP(D2,A2:B7,1,1))
```

So, an interpolation formula, takes the price for the nearest lowest value and adds the amount extra necessary...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT #2**

Presume you have following **named ranges**:

[image: Named Ranges]

- **Consumption** being a list of consumption thresholds sorted ascending;
- **Costs** being a list of prices for each consumption threshold;
- **Consumed** being the quantity of actual consumption.
- **Bound** being the `200` units of increment in your example.

Based on the following **assumptions**:

1. If the consumed quantity is closer to the lower bound, we will only use the price of the lower bound;
2. If the consumed quantity is closer to the higher bound, we will calculate a weighted average price using the following equation:

> `Weighted Average Price (WAP) = w * p + w' * p'`

Based on the price list provided above from my example,

> If the consumed quantity is `720`
>
> **w** = (200-120)/200 = 0.4
>
> **w'** = 1 - w = 0.6
>
> **p** = 80 being the cost for quantity `600`
>
> **p'** = 100 being the cost for quantity `800`
>
> **WAP** = 0.4 * 80 + 0.6 * 100 = **92**

Given the structure of the price equation, it can be re-written using **SUMPRODUCT** function as below:

```
WAP = SUMPRODUCT({w,w'},{p,p'})
```

To find the range of quantity weights `{w,w'}` from the above formula, you can use the following **array formula** which needs to be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
{=ABS({0,1}-(Bound-MOD(Consumed,Bound))/Bound)}
```

> Here **MOD** function is used to find out the residual quantity above `600` which is `120`. The subtraction from `{0,1}` will return `{-0.4,0.6}`, then use **ABS** function to turn all values into positive.

To find the price range `{p,p'}`, you can use another **array formula** which also needs to be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
{=INDEX(Costs,N(IF(1,MATCH(MROUND(Consumed,Bound),Consumption,0)-IF(MOD(Consumed,Bound)<100,{0,0},{1,0}))))}
```

> Here I used **MROUND** function as suggested by @JvdV to find the closest bound and then use **INDEX+MATCH** to return the corresponding prices. The **IF** function will return either `{0,0}` or `{1,0}` which will determine if the looked up prices are from two bounds or from the same bound, which is depended on if the consumed quantity is closer to higher or lower bound.

Lastly, combined the above two **array formulas** within the **SUMPRODUCT** function as shown below:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(ABS({0,1}-(Bound-MOD(Consumed,Bound))/Bound)*INDEX(Costs,N(IF(1,MATCH(MROUND(Consumed,Bound),Consumption,0)-IF(MOD(Consumed,Bound)<100,{0,0},{1,0})))))}
```

> It is also an **array formula** which needs to be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the formula bar.

[image: Solution1]

If I change the consumed quantity to `650`, based on my first assumption, the price should be `80` as shown below:

[image: Solution2]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. Have been away for a while. I need to thoroughly read / test your suggestions but before anything would like to thank you all for your kind help on that matter. You really rock ;)

Julien.