# How would I extract values within 0.20 of every half-integer, then extract again only values nearest to each half-integer? (with DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

In below fact table, how would I construct a DAX calculated column to:

1. extract [Order] values/rows within 0.20 of every half-integer {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0}
2. extract again [Order] values/rows which are nearest to every half-integer {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0} ?

[Vibration Amplitudes and Frequency Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIlph.png)

I'm thinking that I can start with taking the ABS values of the difference between the actual orders and their half-integer rounded counterparts, then filter for those values less than 0.20.

Stuck on how to extract the [Order] values nearest to each half-integer if multiple orders are within that 0.20 margin.

Comment: Do something like this but you will need to edit it to suit your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000585/4961700

Comment: Please clarify how to select values for the second task?

Comment: Could you explain it with a markdown table of data (using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and explain what results you expect with given samples?

Comment: @rotabor So, if multiple values fall within 0.20 margin of a half-integer, I only want to retain the value that is nearest to said half-integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first result use

```
=LET(a,Table1[Order],FILTER(Table1,(ABS(2*a-ROUND(2*a,0))<=0.4)*(a<=3.2)*(a>=0.3)))
```

where Table1 is the name of the data table (replace it by the real name).

To get the second result use

```
=LET(i,FILTER(Table1,(Table1[Order]<=3.2)*(Table1[Order]>=0.3))
  ,a,TAKE(i,,-1)
  ,b,ABS(2*a-ROUND(2*a,0))
  ,FILTER(i,(b=MIN(b))*(b<=0.4))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the excel formula. 

I would like to take the subset of those values falling within the 0.20 margin of half-integers, then pull only the value nearest to the half-integer from which it deviates, 

eg. 0.49, 0.56, 0.59, and .065 fall within +/- 0.20 of 0.50, I would like to only retain 0.49, since it is nearest to 0.5.

Comment: Done as requested. Please accept/vote if my answer is helpful for you.

Comment: Modified the second formula to reach {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0} range.